# Get attribute names from Postgres XML with xpath

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath

I am at the point where I can get xml nodes:

```
select xml_ from (...) a;
-------------
<something att1="abc" att2="123" att3="foo"/>
...
<something att1="def" att2="456" att3="bar"/>
-------------
```

and

```
select xpath('./@*', xml_) from (...) a;
-------------
{"abc", "123", "foo"}
...
{"def", "456", "bar"}
-------------
```

What I would like to get is

```
select magic(xml_) from (...) a;
-------------
{"att1", "att2", "att3"}
...
{"att1", "att2", "att3"}
-------------
```

Please help. Thank you!!!

The 2nd code snippet runs here ->
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/8570/0

Comment: This doesn't work in Postgres. More to come...

Comment: Probably, if postgres implements XPath 2.0 or above: `select xpath('./@*/name()', xml_) from (...) a;`

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that postgres only implements XPath 1.0 ..